# Compile-time error corresponding to main function in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

Here is my compilation command followed by the error message I receive.
The link where you can see the code is also attached.

```
g++ -Wall `root-config --cflags --ldflags --libs` StevenJohnsonDoubleIntegration.cpp
```

---

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Link](https://sourceware.org/ml/gsl-discuss/2005-q2/msg00020.html)

Comment: C++ != C. Use the tag for the language you're actually using, instead of just grabbing any old tag that seems similar. Tags are meaningful here, and using the proper tag is important. It's also important to make it clear in your question - the title says C and the text says C++, and the tags say both.

Comment: Post the source code. It seems that you don't have any `main()` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to main](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8541594/62576)

Comment: There is a lot of code in that link...

Comment: I included the main function but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error **undefined reference to main** means that at linking time, there was no `main()` function.

Looking at the example code, there is a comment that says:

> Compile with -DTEST_INTEGRATOR to generate this little test
>    program.
>
> ```
> Usage: ./integrator <dim> <tol> <integrand> <maxeval>
> ```
>
> where  = # dimensions,  = relative tolerance,
>     is either 0/1/2 for the three test integrands (see below),
>    and  is the maximum # function evaluations (0 for none).

Looking at the code, the main function is excluded from the build unless this symbol is defined.

So, add `-DTEST_INTEGRATOR` to your command line for compiling. You'll probably also want a `-o integrator` to make the output called `integrator` instead of `a.out`

```
g++ -DTEST_INTEGRATOR -Wall `root-config --cflags --ldflags --libs` StevenJohnsonDoubleIntegration.cpp -o integrator
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more careful,

Comment: So, is that true that in general if some code is old using C, it might not be working using C++ commands?

Comment: It is true that not all C will compile as C++, but usually C can compile as C++ (specifically, C code using features from recent C standard versions that don't exist in C++, or C code using C++ reserved words) . In general I would recommend using a C compiler for C code just to not worry about it.Your issue wasn't a C++ vs C issue though; both allow for conditionally compiled code via preprocessor defines.